# How to perform GPS post-processing

Tags: gps

I'm new to the GPS world. I need to know how to perform post-processing with DGPS. I found definitions on the net of what DGPS, post-processing, etc. are, but, couldn't find clear steps on how to actually do DGPS post-processing. While searching for providers, I found that CORS data Rinex files are available to the public for free download from NOAA.

I don't get what I should do to use the downloaded data to post-process my GPS data. Is any free post-processing software available? Also, I use an Android phone (HTC Magic) as my GPS receiver, and I need to figure out how to enable GPS logging into a file in my Android application so that the GPS data can be used for post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

RTKLIB has many nice features and produces reliable results.